# How to get the NHibernate ISession that is HttpContextScoped by StructureMap

Tags: nhibernate, model-view-controller, structuremap, isession

I'm somewhat new to the MVC framework and in accordance with the following post:
[NHibernate with StructureMap](http://www.kevinwilliampang.com/2010/04/06/setting-up-asp-net-mvc-with-fluent-nhibernate-and-structuremap/) I am not sure how to actually get the HttpContextScoped ISession in my controller?

I'm sure there is a simple way to do this but I am unsure.

Also, it's a small project and I don't want to go overboard with Enterprise Design Patterns.

Thanks!

Comment: The blog post you mention explains how to do it. What is your question?

Comment: FYI the author replied AFTER I posted here.

Answer (score 1):

did you try writting this line in your  action method of your controller ?

```
ISession session = ObjectFactory.GetInstance<ISession>();
```